# Draw a graph with dots in specific points

Tags: graph, stata

Can you please help me to draw a graph in Stata given example data below?

I need to have dots (or different figures) as on the blue line that correspond to the X-axis and are in line with p-values in the data. For instance, if the p-value is <0.01 then it is "Star"; if 0.01<=p-value<0.05 - "Circle" and if 0.05<=p-value<0.10 - "Square". "Star", "Circle" and "Square" preferably explained in the legend below the graph.  I just used:

```
line  Beta Beta_2 Beta_3 Period
```

[image]

```
 Period Beta    p-value Beta-2  p-value-2   Beta-3  p-value-3
   1    -0.035  (0.000) -0.022  (0.000)   -0.022    (0.000)
   2    -0.025  (0.000) -0.012  (0.009)   -0.012    (0.009)
   3    -0.033  (0.000) -0.025  (0.000)   -0.025    (0.077)
   4     0.084  (0.000)  0.077  (0.000)    0.077    (0.215)
```

Comment: Please show your code so far.

Comment: I just used: line  Beta Beta-2 Beta-3 Period (Beta-2 and Beta-3 are Beta_2 and Beta_3)

Comment: Never paraphrase or translate syntax. Always give exactly what you typed.

Comment: You can use `scatteri` or marker label options to add symbols as text at particular positions.